# Why am I getting "missing right parenthesis" for this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

This query seems completely legit, I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Query:

```
UPDATE "PROPS"
SET "PROPS"."FLAGGED" = NULL
WHERE "PROPS"."ID"   IN
  (SELECT "PROPS"."ID"
  FROM "PROPS"
  INNER JOIN "PINS"
  ON "PROPS"."PIN_ID"            = "PINS"."ID"
  WHERE "PINS"."CIRCUIT_SPEC_ID" = 10248
  AND "PROPS"."FLAGGED"          = 'WARN'
  ORDER BY pins.pin_type_id ASC);
```

Comment: Try removing the `order by` to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: or adding  `GROUP BY pins.pin_type_id` to the end

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that did remove the error.  This SQL was generated by a Rails ActiveRecord Oracle Adapter library so I'll need to file a bug upstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle doesn't always allow `order by` in subqueries.  It is allowed in subqueries in the `from` clause.  Otherwise, using `rownum` to get the first value doesn't work.  Apparently, it doesn't work in the `in` clause.

Sadly, this is very poorly documented.  On the [page documenting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52152) `in`, it just specifies that a subquery is allowed.  On the [page documenting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) `select`, subqueries would seem to be allowed to have an `order by` clause.  I am not sure if this is an error in the documentation or that I am misreading it.  In any case, the `order by` in this context wouldn't really be doing anything.